# mySQL Partitioning table by MD5?

Tags: mysql, md5, unique, partitioning

i got an mySQL Table with an uniqueID in MD5 (varchar32).
What would be the best way to use Partition on this?

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

PARTITION BY KEY

because it can accept varchar, whereas HASH needs an expression that return an integer. RANGE partitioning is meaningless since you are using hash values for the key.